# Why would $\Delta x = dx$?

Tags: calculus

My textbook has a problem that says to "compare $dy$ and $\Delta y$". I know how to do this in principle as we went over it in class.

However, the problem states to assume that "$\Delta x = dx = .1$". As far as I understand, $\Delta x$ refers to the value used to get the secant line, and $dx$ is the value used to get the tangent line. The limit of $\Delta x = x + h -x$ as $x$ approaches $0$ is $0$.

So why on earth would $\Delta x$ equal $dx$ unless $dy$ and $\Delta y$ were the same? Which the question seems to be assuming they aren't, and also which I'm finding they're not on solving the question.

Comment: Can you post the exact wording if the question? $dx$ is a differential, so isn't a number. $\Delta x$ is the difference between two $x$ values. Sometimes we compare $dy/dx\cdot\Delta x$ to $\Delta y$.

Comment: They're not the same, they're not even the same conceptually. However, one could say that a very small $\Delta x$ can approximate $dx$.

Comment: *"So why on earth would $\Delta x$ equal $dx$ unless $dy$ and $\Delta y$ were the same?"* Do you think the vertical distance to the secant line and tangent line are necessarily the same? Just look at a picture!

Comment: @jdods In some calculus courses, $dx$ and $dy$ are sometimes treated as sides of a triangle with hypotenuse on the tangent line (just like $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ are sides of a triangle with hypotenuse on the secant line). This is more digestible than bona fide differential forms to students with less math background.

Answer (score 4):

$dx$ can be any number you like, in particular it can be $\Delta x$ (take a look at the picture below). Of course, since the approximation of a differentiable function by its tangent line at $x = a$ gets better the closer we are to $a$, one generally considers $dx$ to be very small (in order for $dy$ to approximate $\Delta y$ quite well).

[image]